# Compiler Error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbluetooth

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, makefile

Hi I'm running a a very simple makefile with one line

> g++ -o application main.cpp -lbluetooth

but I get the compile error

> g++ -o application main.cpp -lbluetooth
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbluetooth

Could someone tell me what I need to do to fix this? What package do I need to install? Or do I need to fix a symbolic link?

Answer (score 2):

Ok installing the following packages fixed it:

> apt-get install libbluetooth3 libbluetooth3-dbg libbluetooth-dev

Answer (score 0):

You need to install package with libraries for bluetooth.

I guess: `apt-get install bluez-libs*`

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have installed `Bluez` although maybe not successfully. Running your command in terminal gives the error `E: Unable to locate package bluez-libs*`?

Comment: I've just done `apt-get install bluez-utils` and it says `bluez-utils is already the newest version.`
`

Comment: Maybe try: `apt-get install bluez-libs-devel`

Comment: What does `apt-cache search bluez` returns?